# having a high score in PGRE test is enough for me to be accepted im astrophysics' graduate programs?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

I am a law student. I am studying physics on my own to attend a PGRE test because Astrophysics always fascinates me. I want to have a Masters Degree in astrophysics but I have no Bachelor's Degree in astronomy or physics or math. Instead, my Bachelor's will be in law.

My question is: will having a high score on the PGRE test be enough for me to be accepted for graduate programs in astrophysics?

Comment: Have you ever taken any astronomy % physics & math course throughout you bachelor degree ?

Comment: If you didn't take calculus level mathematics, university chemistry, and or university physics you might want to start an undergraduate degree in physics or astronomy first. If you do get accepted into a program you would more than likely have to take quite a few undergrad classes to "catch up" to the level you would need for your graduate level courses.

Comment: I've taken math 2 & physics & chemistry in high school. but i've never taken such a courses while studying law.

Comment: Taking calculus in high school would help ? @leth

Comment: I have flagged this as a possible duplicate of the Ph.D. admissions program even though it's about Masters, since there seems to be a large gap in the OP's knowledge of graduate programs in general.

Comment: Does "PGRE" mean "physics GRE", i.e. the GRE Physics Subject Test?  If so, the short answer to your question is no.  GRE scores are only a small part of the admission decision; your undergraduate record and letters of recommendation are far more important.  Unfortunately, it doesn't sound like your undergraduate work has been anywhere close to sufficient to preparing you for graduate study in physics.